# How to create constructor with array as parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have class Wektor and constructors with one, three and four parameters. I need one more with float array as parameter, but have no idea how to create it

```
Wektor(){
        this -> x = 0;
        this -> y = 0;
        this -> z = 0;
        this -> w = 0;
    }

    Wektor(float x){
        this -> x = x;
    }

Wektor(float x, float y, float z) {
        this -> x = x;
        this -> y = y;
        this -> z = z;
    }

    Wektor(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        this -> x = x;
        this -> y = y;
        this -> z = z;
        this -> w = w;
    }
```

Comment: `Wektor(std::array<float,4> a){` maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can i set any variable instead 4 ? I guess 4 is array size?

Comment: In case you need to specify the size dynamically you should use a `std::vector<float>`. You can read more about that in the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Creating a constructor for a c-array

C-arrays can't be passed by copy, but they can be passed by reference. There are two ways to do this.

**First way:**

```
using four_floats = float[4]; 

Wektor(four_floats const& arr) {
    x = arr[0];
    y = arr[1];
    z = arr[2];
    w = arr[3]; 
}
```

**Second way.** This way uses evil, vile syntax that's really ugly.

```
Wektor(float const (&arr)[4]) {
    x = arr[0];
    y = arr[1];
    z = arr[2];
    w = arr[3]; 
}
```

#### Creating a constructor from `std::array`

This one is pretty straight-forward.

```
Wector(std::array<float, 4> const& arr) {
    x = arr[0];
    y = arr[1];
    z = arr[2];
    w = arr[3];
}
```